# Insertar streaming en html

Tags: html, html5

Para una pagina web necesito insertar un streaming rtmp. El problema es que no quiero usar terceros, quiero yo directamente incluir el streaming en el html. Hay alguna forma de hacer eso? Estoy tratando de convertir el streaming a http mediante vlc. Pero no funciona.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video src="http://192.168.0.29:8080" autoplay>

    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

En primer lugar, debe configurar un servidor de transmisión de medios. 
Puede usar **Wowza**, **red5** o **nginx-rtmp-module**. Lea su documentación y configuración en el sistema operativo que desee. Todos los motores son compatibles con HLS (Protocolo Http Live Stream desarrollado por Apple). Deberá leer la documentación para la configuración. Ejemplo con `nginx-rtmp`-module:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

        application show {
            live on;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path /mnt/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            deny play all;
        }
    }
} 

server {
    listen 8080;

    location /hls {
        # Disable cache
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

        # CORS setup
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';

        # allow CORS preflight requests
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        types {
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }

        root /mnt/;
    }
}
```

Después de la instalación del servidor y la configuración que se realizó correctamente, debe usar un software de codificador rtmp **(OBS, wirecast ...)** para comenzar a transmitir como youtube o twitchtv. En el lado del cliente (navegador en su caso) puede usar **Videojs** o **JWplayer** para reproducir video para el usuario final. Puede hacer algo como a continuación para Videojs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Live Streaming</title>
    <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" height="360" width="640" controls preload="none">
    <source src="http://localhost:8080/hls/stream.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
</video>
<script>
    var player = videojs('#player');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

No necesita agregar otros complementos como flash (porque usamos HLS no rtmp). Este reproductor puede funcionar bien entre navegadores sin flash.

Comment: Me da un error sobre que no encontro los archivos que linkeaste